How to split multiple fields in a data.table and expand the rows correspondingly in R?
I am working with a data.table in R where multiple fields can contain multiple values separated by semicolons. I am trying to separate these values into individual rows, with each value corresponding to a new row in the table. However, the challenge is that the separate fields are related and need to be split and expanded correspondingly.
example data:
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(probe = c('A', 'B', 'C'), # there are many columns in real data
                 gene = c('geneA', 'geneB;geneC', 'geneD;geneH;geneI;geneO'), 
                 type = c('mRNA', 'mRNA;miRNA', 'mRNA;miRNA;mRNA;miRNA')) 

df
    probe                    gene                  type
1:      A                   geneA                  mRNA
2:      B             geneB;geneC            mRNA;miRNA
3:      C geneD;geneH;geneI;geneO mRNA;miRNA;mRNA;miRNA

expected output:
df.new <- data.table(probe = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
                     gene = c('geneA', 'geneB', 'geneC', 'geneD', 'geneH', 'geneI', 'geneO'), 
                     type = c('mRNA', 'mRNA', 'miRNA', 'mRNA', 'miRNA', 'mRNA', 'miRNA'))

df.new
    probe   gene   type
1:      A  geneA   mRNA
2:      B  geneB   mRNA
3:      B  geneC  miRNA
4:      C  geneD   mRNA
5:      C  geneH  miRNA
6:      C  geneI   mRNA
7:      C  geneO  miRNA


Thank you for your kindly suggestions

An approach using strsplit
library(data.table)

df[, lapply(.SD[,c("gene", "type")], \(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))), by = probe]
    probe   gene   type
   <char> <char> <char>
1:      A  geneA   mRNA
2:      B  geneB   mRNA
3:      B  geneC  miRNA
4:      C  geneD   mRNA
5:      C  geneH  miRNA
6:      C  geneI   mRNA
7:      C  geneO  miRNA


You can use separate_longer_delim from {tidyr}.
library(tidyr)

separate_longer_delim(df, c(gene, type), ';')

#   probe  gene  type
# 1     A geneA  mRNA
# 2     B geneB  mRNA
# 3     B geneC miRNA
# 4     C geneD  mRNA
# 5     C geneH miRNA
# 6     C geneI  mRNA
# 7     C geneO miRNA


Using splitstackshape package :
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, c("gene", "type"), sep = ";", 
                        direction = "long", type.convert = FALSE)

#     probe   gene   type
#   <char> <char> <char>
#1:      A  geneA   mRNA
#2:      B  geneB   mRNA
#3:      B  geneC  miRNA
#4:      C  geneD   mRNA
#5:      C  geneH  miRNA
#6:      C  geneI   mRNA
#7:      C  geneO  miRNA

